# How to capture popup webpage in tabcontrol browser

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How to capture the popup when clicked when the button is clicked in webbrowser it opens a popup webpage i need to capture the popup webpage to the tabcontrolbrowser

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your specific issue. Also please show some kind of attempt at what you have tried so we can better help you with your issue.

Comment: I using a site which has some popup while login the member area page is displayed in popup  when i use webbrowser for login the member area is popup and i need to capture the popup in the tabcontrol browser

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying ask for.  I have had a similar issue where I must display a form nested within another form. To do so I have used code similar to this:

```
aForm = New TLoginForm
aForm.TopLevel = False
pnlLoginPanel.Controls.Add(aForm)
If aForm.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        aForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End If
aForm.Show()
```

I like using a panel control to contain the form I am instantiating.  It is just easier for me to understand the bounds of the form when it is getting displayed and it is easier to use a panel control's Controls.Add ability than a tab-page's alone. When I am using a log-in form or another type of form nested within another form I create a panel control to 'hold' the form inside and provide bounds for it to be displayed in. Then the TopLevel property of the log-in form must be set to False so that the form I am displaying knows it will not be displayed on its own as a top level window. Be sure to do this as an error can be encountered otherwise. The WindowState.Maximized is to ensure that the form fills the panel.